# Using an HTML site's search engine (USPS tracking example)

Tags: html, search, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

*edit: I exchanged the tracking number in the url for '########' for privacy reasons.

I would like to create a python program which will take an user-input tracking number and retrieve the shipping information from the package carrier.  My first attempt is using USPS as an example.  My problem is that even though I know the URL, what I think I need to do is someone use the site's search/query engine.  Here is an example of my code:
    import urllib2
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import os

```
#usps tracking example
url = 'https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction.action?tRef=fullpage&tLc=1&tLabels=################'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read(),from_encoding='utf-8')

text_file = open(os.path.join('C:/Python27/','tracking_info.txt'), 'w')
text_file.write(soup.prettify(encoding='utf-8'))
text_file.close()

usps_details = soup.find('tbody','details')
```

In the browser based results, it stores the data that I am interested in to a 'tbody' tag with the class 'details'.  When I read the url, I am reading what looks like the tool, rather than the results returned from the tool, yet I have no idea how to implement this in my program.  I apologize for any confusion and if the topic already exists.  I did try and search but I think that I may not be using the correct vocabulary.